# PHP Loop Over ONLY Different Arrays

Tags: php

I have a single array with several of the same values. And I only want to loop over DIFFERENT values. How could I go about doing this?

Example

```
166-01 001;09;UO;
166-01 001;09;UO;
166-01 001;09;UO;
166-01 001;09;UO;
166-01 001;09;UO;
166-01 001;09;UO;
166-01 001;09;UO;_86
166-01 001;09;UO;_86
166-01 001;09;UO;_86
166-01 001;09;UO;_86
166-01 001;09;UO;_86
166-01 001;09;UO;_86_97
166-01 001;09;UO;_86_97
166-01 001;09;UO;_86_97
166-01 001;09;UO;_86_97_108
166-01 001;09;UO;_86_97_108
166-01 001;09;UO;_86_97_108_119
166-01 001;09;UO;_86_97_108_119
```

I have that in a single array, but I only want to loop for the different ones. So it would loop once for nothing, then once for _86, then once for _86_97, then once for _86_97_108, and then once for _86-97_108_119. So only loop for different key values,

or would there be a way to count the number of different keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`array_unique()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

```
foreach(array_unique($array) as $key => $value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/array_unique), perhaps used in conjunction with [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/array_keys).

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the ones you've passed:

```
$passed = array();

foreach ($array as $value) {
  if (!in_array($value, $passed)) {
    $passed[] = $value;
  }
}

print_r($passed);
```

Or easier:

```
$array = array_unique($array);
```